# Compound expression vs. Expression vs. Sub-expression

Tags: c++, expression

I feel I got a little confused here distinguishing sub-expression from expression.

`Compound expression` - An expression involving more than one operator.

E.g. `1 + 1 * 1`

`Expression` - An operator with one or more operands.

E.g `1 + 1` or `+ 1`

is there a level below the expression which is called a sub-expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An expression may not have an operator.  For example, in the following:

```
int a = 0;
a;
```

`a` is an expression.  An expression is, to quote the C++ Standard, "a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation" (C++03 5/1).  Here, `a` is an "operand" even though there is no operator.

---

A subexpression is any expression that is a piece of a larger expression.  So, in

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
a * b + c * d;
```

`a * b` and `c * d` are subexpressions.

---

The word "compound" is usually used with respect to *statements*, not *expressions*.  A compound statement is a pair of braces that may contain a sequence of other statements.  For example, a function body is almost always a compound statement, as are many loop bodies.

Usually, complex expressions are just referred to simply as "expressions" and their parts are referred to as subexpressions.

Answer (score 6):

- The C++ standard defines what an
  expression is in a whole chapter (Chapter 5 if I recall correctly).
- The C++ standard does not define what a compound expression is
- The C++ standard defines a `full expression` as an expression which isn't a subexpression of any other expression

Example:

`a + 4 + 5;`

`a + 4 + 5` is a full expression. Neither `a` nor `4` nor `a + 4` in that expression are full expressions (although they are (sub)expressions) because it is a subexpression of the above expression

Answer (score 4):

Although you've already received some good answers, I'll add one more detail that may not be apparent from those answers: a sub-expression can also be a completely separate expression that is not lexically part of the full expression being evaluated.

The obvious example of this is when you call a function that uses a default argument. In this case, assigning the default value to the argument is considered a sub-expression of the calling expression. For example, given something like:

```
int f(int const &x=2) { return x; }
int y = f()+4;
```

the `f()` creates a temporary `int` that's initialized with the value 2 and then passed by reference to `f`. The creation and initialization of that temporary is a subexpression of the full expression `y= f() + 4` even though the text `int const &x=2` is entirely separate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the above definitions, `2+3`, `-4` and `*ptr` are expressions. What can be shorter than this? Maybe only identifiers and constants, such as `4`.